# Unhandled exception in anjular.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs to make a MVC web application...But it gives an error when i'm opening it on internet explorer... But I don't receive an error in other browsers and views are not loading either when click on the links.

**This is the error received in Internet Explorer**

```
Unhandled exception at line 33, column 487 in //localhost:18012/Scripts/angular.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/modulerr?p0=sampleApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.27%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A196)%0A%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A273)%0A%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A487)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A386)%0A%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288)%0A%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207)%0A%20%20%20at%20ec%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A307)%0A%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A168)%0A%20%20%20at%20dc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A380)%0A%20%20%20at%20Wc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A18012%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415)
```

I have attached my angular model below. Please help me to solve this.

**app.js**

```
//Define an angular module for our app

    var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.

        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/homeContent.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).

        when('/AddNewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).

        when('/ShowOrders', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).

        when('/players', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/playersMen.html',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }]);


sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

});
```

Comment: well can you try using the unminified version? otherwise I would say look at the network stack and see if the angular-route.js is being loaded after angular and before your app, it looks like it can't find the ngRoute module.

Comment: yeah i have forgotten to add angular-route.js but when i add it it throws another exception 

Exception was thrown at line 5, column 16502 in localhost:18012/Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are inject $routeProvider

please make sure you loaded:

> angular-route.js

cdn:

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-route.js

when u loaded,then

add dependency to your app with ngRoute

> angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: yeah i have forgotten to add angular-route.js
but when i add it it throws another exception 

Exception was thrown at line 5, column 16502 in http://localhost:18012/Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [ngRoute]);

but stil having the above error

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva ngRoute is angular route module name, so need add it as indentify string

Comment: var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

still geting the error

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva do u have load other js lib before jQuery and they required jQuery?,delete them,place jquery before angular if u need jquery. Advice: when u coding, could use un-minify file, make u clear for any Exception.

Comment: there was a jquery file

<script src="Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

i comment it..then it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to inject 'ngRoute' in your angular module in the way:

```
     var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Another thing is include angular-route.js in your index.html file

This will resolve your problem

Comment: still getting an error

Exception was thrown at line 5, column 16502 in localhost:18012/Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: your routing error has been resolved now. And for jquery exception, are you using jquery inside ur script.. if yes then please specify that method

Answer (score 0):

Your module is missing ngRoute dependency.Make sure first you add angular-route.min.js
Then added ngRoute dependency inside your app

Your app should look like below.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Add script reference to html exact after angular.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: added the dependency
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [ngRoute]);

but now getting the following error

Exception was thrown at line 5, column 16502 in http://localhost:18012/Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: is there any other jquery file in your project? and is it browser specific?

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva does it giving jquery-1.10.2.js 404 not found error in console of browser?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to another case with similar error, if you do not `VS2015 US` cord that will find it: references the Angular after **platformOverrides.js**

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <p id="deviceready" class="event">Connecting to Device</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"</script>
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```